# How to replace last matched character in string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

i want to replace last input character from keyboard to ''

My String Input are

sample string

```
"<p><strong>abscd sample text</strong></p>"

"<p>abscd sample text!</p>"
```

My last character is dynamic that can be any thing between
a to z, A to Z, 0 to 9, any special characters([~ / < > & ( . ]  ).
So i need to replace just that character

for example in Sample 1 i need to replace "t" and in sample 2 in need to replace "!"

I tried below code. but it id not worked for me

```
 var replace = '/'+somechar+'$/';
```

Any way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Step one

to replace the a character in a string, use `replace()` function of javaScript. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is the MDN specification:

> Returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.  The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match.

## Step two

you need to location the character to be replaced through regular expression. You want to replace the **last character** of a string and this could be expressed as /(.+)(.)$/. `.` stands for any character, `+` means more than one character. Here `(.+)` matches all the character before the last one. `(.)` matches the last character.

What you want to replace is the one inside the second brackets. Thus you use the same string matched in the first bracket with `$1` and replace whatever after it.

Here is the code to realize your intention:

```
text = 'abscd sample text';
text.replace(/(.+)(.)$/, '$1!');
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use regular expressions? How about `str = str.slice(0, -1);` ? This will remove the last character.

If you need to replace a specific character, do it like this:

```
var replace = new RegExp(somechar + '$');
str = str.replace(replace, '');
```

You cannot use slashes in a string to construct a RegEx. This is different from PHP, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand which character you want to replace to what, but i think, you should use replace() function in JS: http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

```
string.replace(regexp/substr,newstring)
```

This means all keyboard character:

```
[\t\n ./<>?;:"'`!@#$%^&*()[]{}_+=-|\\]
```

And this way you can replace all keyboard character before `<` mark to `""`

```
 string.replace("[a-zA-Z0-9\t\n ./<>?;:"'`!@#$%^&*()[]{}_+=-|\\]<","<")
```