# Replace last matched character in substring using jquery / regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I know this question is similar to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356861) so apologies if considered a duplicate.

The result I'm trying to achieve is to check divs with a **class** of **gallery-info**

```
$('.gallery-info').each(function() {

});
```

I set up a condition to return a substring if the character count of each div is greater than 140 characters. (Twitter)

```
$('.gallery-info').each(function() {
  var descLength = 140;
  var str = $(this).text();
  var patt = new RegExp(/[,;.:!()&\s$]/g);

  if (str.length > descLength) {
   $(this).text(str.substr(0, descLength) + "...");
  } 
});
```

**IF**

The last character of the substring matches the **patt** var.
Return substring -1 and concat "..."

**ELSE**

Return substring and concat "..."

I've been having a brain fart on this and I believe I can achieve this in Vanilla JS with str.replace() and str.charAt() but I need to do this in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think updating your IF condition with below should work fine.

```
  if (str.length > descLength) {
        if(patt.test(str[descLength-1])) {
          $(this).text(str.substr(0, descLength-1) + "...");
        } else {
          $(this).text(str.substr(0, descLength) + "...");     
        }
  }
```

**CODEPEN**: https://codepen.io/azimjs/pen/mBqjNY

Comment: Thank you for this. I knew I was on the right track. Life saver.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works as you've described.

```
$('.gallery-info').each(function() {
  var descLength = 140;
  var str = $(this).text();
  var patt = new RegExp(/[,;.:!()&\s$]/g);
  if (str.length > descLength) {
    var substring = str.substr(0, descLength);
    var lastChar = substring[substring.length-1];
    if (lastChar.match(patt)) {
      $(this).text(str.substr(0, descLength -1) + "...");
    } else {
      $(this).text(str.substr(0, descLength) + "...");
    }
  }
});
```

**Codepen**

https://codepen.io/foozie3moons/pen/GMOBvw

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I believe it to be unnecessary to split the string since strings are inherently character arrays.